# React.isValidElement() fails to Detect Stateless Components

Tags: reactjs

I'm finding a problem after update my react version from to 16.9.0 to 16.13.1.

The function `isValidElement(element)` no longer returns *true* for stateless components.

It seems to be an issue with the property **$$typeof**.

The function is expecting a value of `Symbol(react.element)` but the stateless components all seem to be `Symbol(react.memo)`.

Anyone else run into this and did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0):

If you see the changelog for v16.12.0 [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#react-is)

> They've fixed a bug where lazy and memo were considered elements and not components.

Are you sure your functional component is exported as is and not as React.memo(YourFnComponent)

> You might want to downgrade to v16.11.0 to check if v16.12.0 version is causing the error you're getting.

Morever I checked the tests [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/blob/master/packages/react-is/src/__tests__/ReactIs-test.js) and see for a memo type component, it's there.

Comment: After doing so additional debugging it looks like the issue may be cause by `react-redux`. If I create a stateless component and test it agains React.isValidElement() it works fine. if I take the same element and use `connect(mapStateToProps, actions)(MyComponent)` then the **$$typeof** is *Symbol(react.memo)*. I think My react version is OK I need to play with react-redux a bit more.